# Is it not possible to have a multi page app in chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Hi I am trying to create a chrome app.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('sample.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 400,
      'left': 0,
      'top': 0
    }
  });
```

This creates a window I could not navigate to another page.Is it not possible to do it? If so Is there some other option to do it? Can some one please help me

Comment: Open a new window?

Comment: how to load all pages in same window?Is it possible? @DanielHerr

Comment: I think you load it in the same window. According to Ben Wells's answer in [How to communicate between multiple windows of the same chrome app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765870/how-to-communicate-between-multiple-windows-of-the-same-chrome-app?rq=1), "Multiple chrome windows are not completely separate. They share a single thread and object space, however the window object is different for each. So, you can reach into another window and execute a function there, or manipulate state in other ways and it is acceptable and supported."

Comment: Also from another [previous question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348790/how-to-navigate-to-different-pages-in-a-chrome-app-without-creating-a-new-window?rq=1)."You can't navigate within a Chrome App window (Content Security Policy), although you can navigate to an external browser if you set the target attribute of the <a> element to "_blank". What you have to do, if you really want links to appear to work normally, is intercept the click on the link by setting an event handler and then changing the DOM from within JavaScript."

Comment: How to change DOM within javascript? Can you please explain me?@Mr.Rebot

Comment: You can start here @Anu http://www.w3schools.com/js/